# Segregation of Quotation emails from the others

Tags: python

I am working on email parsing where i want to segregate the quotation emails from the others and extract only those emails(quotation). Right now i am able to read all the unread emails and extracting all of them but not able to find a way to extract only quotation emails. I would be really grateful if you could suggest any way to do that.

Thank you.

I am able to extracting all the unread emails.

Comment: Could you add some code please?

Comment: email_ids = data[0].split()
    for num in email_ids:
        result, email_data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
        date = email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime(email_message['Date'])
        subject = decode_subject(email_message['Subject'])
        if re.search(
                r'advise exw|required quote|request air freight|rate request',subject, re.IGNORECASE):
            mail.copy(num, 'Quotation')

Comment: In this i am able to extract the quotation emails successfully but when i am copying these to Quotation folder, data is mismatching.

Comment: You should add the code in the question and format it properly.